# There are no available DSEFS locations to write data to

Tags: datastax

I have problem with my datastax docker image. I tried to copy a file on ddsefs but I have this error:

```
dsefs dsefs://127.0.1.1:5598/ > cp file:orifile.text destFile.text
Server error: java.io.IOException: There are no available DSEFS locations to write data to. DSEFS nodes are either unavailable or low on free space. Check node health and connectivity, add more storage space and/or adjust min_free_space if needed.
```

Could you please help me?

Regards,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically says you haven't given it enough free storage space. There is some reserve set by `min_free_space` (configured via `dse.yaml`), that DSEFS will never touch. Therefore if `min_free_space` setting is larger than the actual free storage space you on your node, you'll get this error.

Comment: I'm using docker image. In the log I see these ERROR/WARNING


`WARN  [dsefs-netty-worker-1] DSEFS LocationService.scala:455 - Local location a80ec97d-05a4-4fd0-9024-210a5083610e is low on free space. Available free space is 1332555776 bytes.`


`INFO  [dsefs-netty-worker-1] DSEFS Native.java:149 - Could not load JNR POSIX Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).`

Comment: Change `min_free_space` in dse.yaml to something low like 100 MB

Comment: I modified `/opt/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.yml` file uncommented the property `min_free_space` and setted the value at `104857600` (100MB), but:

` Loading settings from file:/opt/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
ERROR Unable to start server. Exiting...
org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block collection; expected <block end>, but found Key;  in 'reader', line 603, column 13:min_free_space: 104857600`

Comment: It works. I inserted this block code:

`dsefs_options:
    enabled: true
    keyspace_name: dsefs
    work_dir: /var/lib/dsefs
    public_port: 5598
    private_port: 5599
    data_directories:
      - dir: /var/lib/dsefs/data
        storage_weight: 1.0
        min_free_space: 5368709120`